# I don't want to allow a 9 digit number in textbox

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I don't want to allow a 9 digit number in textbox.Textbox should accept alphabets and any number accept a 9 digit number. And the textbox should not except the 9 digit number even if its written in following format: 123-23-2323

Comment: We help those who help themselves. At least post your attempt.

Comment: So, an 8-digit number, even with dashes (i.e. 82-22-4444) is fine, but 9 digits is invalid?

Comment: what did you try so far?

Comment: perhaps [this](https://icanhazcode.com/speckerman.html) is what you need

Comment: Try max length property and set 9

Comment: @silambarasanvediappan - read the question ... for a start, 9 digits is too many, and secondly, it's only the number of numeric characters that he wants to limit to **eight** (not 9)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

**HTML:**

```
<input type="text" id="txtName" onkeypress="return Allow9NumberOnly(this,event)" />
```

**Jquery:**

```js
function Allow9NumberOnly(item, evt) {
        evt = (evt) ? evt : window.event;
        var charCode = (evt.which) ? evt.which : evt.keyCode;

        if (charCode >= 48 && charCode <= 57) {
            var myText = $(item).val();
            var intCount = 0;
            for (var i = 0; i < myText.length; i++) {

                if (!isNaN(myText[i])) {
                    intCount++;
                }
            }

            if (intCount >= 8) {               
                return false;
            }
        }

        return true;       
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="txtName" onkeypress="return Allow9NumberOnly(this,event)" />
```

============================================

**If you wants to restrict only character 9 then:**

```
function Allow9NumberOnly(item, evt) {
    evt = (evt) ? evt : window.event;
    var charCode = (evt.which) ? evt.which : evt.keyCode;
    if (charCode == 57)
    {
        return false;
    }     

    return true;       
}
```